# How do you change all ng-show dependent variables in an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that has an ng-if attached to it, with a child element that I am changing with an ng-click. The code looks something like the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-if="show">
 <div ng-click="show = !show">Show</div>
</div>
```

Lets say I had 2 **`objects`**, it would load two repeated divs, and there would be two 'show' elements. When I click show, it will only remove one of the repeated elements from the page. I need it to remove both. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide all I would wrap all of it in an outer div and place the "ng-if" there.

```
<div ng-if="show">
<div ng-repeat="object in object">
 <div ng-click="show = !show">Show</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I would however advise to place any logic that modifies data in the TS file instead of in the html view.

Comment: This will not work since `scope` created within [`ngIf` direcftive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) inherits from its parent scope using prototypal inheritance. And changing `show` with `ngClick` right in the template will just change it inside of the newly created scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your template is almost correct, the only thing that is worth mentioning is that:

> The scope created within [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) inherits from its parent scope
>   using prototypal inheritance.

The main caveat of [prototypal inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance) is that setting a primitive value on the child scope shadows the value on the parent scope. There are different approaches of how to avoid this, see the code snippet below:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('mainController', function mainController($scope) {
  var ctrl = this;
  
  $scope.show = true;
  $scope.showList = {value: true};
  $scope.objects = [{}, {}, {}];
  
  $scope.toggleShowVar = function(){
    $scope.show = !$scope.show;
  };
  
  ctrl.show = true;
    
});
```

```html
<!-- JS -->
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="mainController as $mainCtrl">
      <p>This will not work due to scope prototypal inheritance:</p>
      <div ng-if="show">
        <div ng-repeat="object in objects">
          <div ng-click="show = !show">Show {{show}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <p>Using "controller as" will help us:</p>
      <div>
        <div ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-if="$mainCtrl.show">
          <div ng-click="$mainCtrl.show = !$mainCtrl.show">Show {{$mainCtrl.show}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <p>Or simply using "dot in the model":</p>
      <div>
        <div ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-if="showList.value">
          <div ng-click="showList.value = !showList.value">Show {{showList.value}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <p>Or using controller method for toggle:</p>
      <div>
        <div ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-if="show">
          <div ng-click="toggleShowVar()">Show {{show}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <p>Or using $parent to change it in the controller's scope:</p>
      <div>
        <div ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-if="$parent.show">
          <div ng-click="$parent.$parent.show = !$parent.$parent.show ">Show {{$parent.show}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```